# GStreamer + V4L2loopback as Chrome compatible webcam

Tags: google-chrome, gstreamer, v4l2loopback

I am trying to create a virtual camera in Chrome using v4l2loopback where the incoming  video is H264 via RTP.

I have has some success in getting a GStreamer test video recognized in Chrome with `MediaStreamTrack.getSources`:

```
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

This works well, Chrome will display the video test source.

However, when I use an incoming h264/RTP source the device does not show up in `MediaStreamTrack.getSources`. For example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=<IPADDRESS> port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

What is the reason for this? What would the solution be?

I had thought perhaps this is to do with the video formats and perhaps the correct caps needed to be set through v4l2loopback.

Comment: If you run `gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink` in parallel with your two pipelines, does it show output in both cases?

Comment: Ok, just tried this. With the test source it works and there is output. But... when using the ftp pipeline: `Device '/dev/video0' is not a capture device.` It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide output of your second pipeline? It seems that there is some problem with the video format. Looks like `v4l2sink` accepts file format that v4l2loopback` does not understand.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/rc1/9758728

Comment: @maxtaldykin I have 12 hours to award the bounty... even if you have any ideas :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug in gstreamer or v4l2loopback. It is somehow related to how variable frame rate is handled.

I managed to reproduce it in this way:

Start pipeline transmitting video from network to `/dev/video0`

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpserversrc port=5000 \
    ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay \
    ! decodebin \
    ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

Start pipeline transmitting some video to port 5000

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc \
    ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! gdppay \
    ! tcpserversink port=5000
```

Try to get video from `/dev/video0`

```
$ gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! autovideosink
...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Device '/dev/video1' is not a capture device.
```

Now, note the caps for `v4l2sink` in the debug log of the first pipeline.

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt601, framerate=(fraction)0/1
```

It mentions that `framerate=(fraction)0/1`. In gstreamer's terms this means that frame rate is variable. According to `v4l2sink`'s source code it seems that it feed this same frame rate to `v4l2loopback` kernel module but `v4l2loopback` does not understand zero frame rate.
(This is only hypothesis, still need to check if this is what really happens.)

To workaround this bug you can fix frame rate. Just add `videorate` element to the first pipeline:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpserversrc port=5000 \
    ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay \
    ! decodebin \
    ! videorate ! video/x-raw, framerate=25/1 \
    ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

Comment: Thanks – this works. If you ever prove / dis-prove your hypothesis it would be good to know.

Comment: I'll try to investigate this further and contact to developers.

Comment: _For anyone trying this out and getting bad FPSs:_ I added `sync=false` to v4l2sink